# spark exception when using filter() within map()

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, key-value, rdd

i am trying to use filter() inside map() but i get this spark exception:

> RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

i know that spark doesn't allow nested transformations/actions/RDDs, so can any one give me a suggestion how to do it alternatively (without nested transformations or actions), well i have an RDD its tuples are like:

```
 JavaRDD< String[]> RDD
```

i try to map it, giving it a list as an argument, this list contains javaPairRDDs such:

```
List<JavaPairRDD<String,String>> list
JavaRDD< String[]> result = RDD.map(new modifyRDD(list));
```

these lines refers to modifyRDD() function:

```
public static class modifyRDD implements Function <String[], String[]> { 

    List<JavaPairRDD<String,String>> list;
    public modifyRDD (List<JavaPairRDD<String,String>> list ){ this.list=list;}

    public String [] call(String[] t) {

          String[] s = t;

          for (int i = 0; i < NB_TD; i++) {         
            int j=i; 
         // select the appropriate RDD from the RDDs_list to the current index 

            JavaPairRDD<String,String> rdd_i = list.get(i);
            String previousElement=s[j];

           JavaPairRDD<String,String> currentRDD =  rdd_i.filter(line -> line._1().equals(previousElement));

           String newElement=currentRDD.first()._2();   

           s[j]=newElement;
                }

          return   (s) ;

    }


    }
```

so, the problem is in this line

```
  JavaPairRDD<String,String> currentRDD =  rdd_i.filter(line -> line._1().equals(previousElement));
```

now i give an example,suppose that list contains 2 PairRDDs

```
list={PairRDD1={(a,b)(c,d)},PairRDD2={(u,v)(x,y)}..}
```

and my RDD that i want to map contains:

```
 JavaRDD< String[]> RDD = {[a,u],[c,x],[a,x].....}
```

the result that i want is after map():

```
 JavaRDD< String[]> result = {[b,v],[d,y],[b,y].....}
```

Comment: Have you read error message and corresponding JIRA? Spark doesn't support nested actions and transformations the same way as it doesn't support nested RDDs.

Comment: yes i did, but what can i do as an alternative solution

Comment: This problem has been covered so many time on SO... Short answer: a) RDD is small collect and use local variable or broadcast b) RDD is large express this problem as join

Comment: it is large in my case, would you give me steps that i can follow,please

Comment: @zero323 if you have noticed i am using a list of pairRDDS inside the map function, bcz with every single index i need diffrent pairRDD,  so how can i do join of my RDD with all of those pairRDDS( if you see the exapmle for eg, i have 2 pairRDDS, in my case i cant know how many pairRDDs are in the list)

Answer (score 0):

i changed the type of the list from List> to List>> list to avoid dealing with RDDs inside the map(), now i have no exception (offcourse bcz i have no nested transformations), but what i am not sure about it is if my new code is efficient, bcz the List> is large, and for searching an element i used a loop "for" (means i have to sweep the whole List> to get the element that i want) so i ask you as experts to give me remarks about it (using the loop for), and give suggestion to ameliorate it. thank you

this is the map() function after modification

```
  public static class modifyRDD implements Function <String[], String[]> { 

    List<List<Tuple2<String,String>>> list;
    public modifyRDD (List<List<Tuple2<String,String>>> list ){ this.list=list;}

    public String [] call(String[] t) {

          String[] s = t;

          for (int i = 0; i < NB_TD; i++) {         

         // select the appropriate lookup_list 

            List<Tuple2<String,String>> list_i = list.get(i);
            String previousElement=s[i];
            String newElement="";

            for (int k = 0; k < list_i.size(); k++){

            Tuple2<String,String> sk1 = list_i.get(k);
            if (sk1._1.equals( previousElement)){  newElement=sk1._2;}

            }


           s[i]= newElement;
                }
         return(s);
                                   }
```